# Can motion be considered a dimension?

Tags: kinematics, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

Okay, go easy on me, I’m in no way any kind of physicist, or even a scientist, I graduated High School and that’s it, but I do have a very mechanically based mind, (probably why I wound up a Diesel Mechanic by trade) and I’ve been giving some thought and doing a bit of research and doing some -what I can only assume is- extremely rudimentary “brainstorming” if you can call it that, and I’m wondering what the experts think.. Hopefully the science community is forgiving to total amateurs who have no idea what they are talking about, I just want to learn!

I always understood the way to identify how many dimensions that say a point occupies is by how many coordinates you need to locate it. X, Y, Z, etc. So I got to thinking of how you would give coordinates for a point inside of a three dimensional cube that is moving through space, you would use the X, Y, and Z axis to locate a point within said cube, but you could do that one second and then do it a second later with the same three coordinates and you would have a different point in space if you back up and look because the object that you based your measurements off of is in motion. The tradesman in me said, “you don’t measure off of anything that isn’t fixed genius, that’s bad carpentry, let alone bad science.” But then I got to thinking that what is truly “still” in the universe? It’s all based on perspective... help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe seems very similar to the concept of 'phase space'. Phase space is not thought of in terms of actual spatial dimensions, but it does take from the concept of 'space' the idea of multiple independent degrees of freedom.

So my recommendation to you would be to try and find introductions to the concept of phase space.

In the wikipedia article about phase space the introduction is rather short, and then it moves to more abstract ideas that are outside the scope of your question. So what I mean to say: you can take the wikipedia article about phase space as a starting piont, but it may well be that there are other places with more extended introduction.

---

Incidentally: there is a groping, rambling nature to your question. I assume that is because you don't have the concepts in place that would allow you to write your question with a sense of direction.

So I rather expect that any answers you do get to your question will be wildly different to each other. Different people will pick up different parts of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Time is a dimension, rather than motion (which is what an object does when it travels through space and time).

To locate a moving object, you need to specify three position coordinates and one time coordinate. So a moving object inhabits 4-dimensional *spacetime*, and its path through space as a function of time can be thought of as a single geometric object which we often refer to as the *worldline* of the object.

The main thing to keep in mind is that the 3 space dimensions and the time dimension work very differently. The obvious difference is that you can only travel forward in time. There are more subtle differences between them that mostly start to matter when relativity is involved (namely, they have opposite signs in the metric signature), so often theoretical physicists refer to the dimension of a spacetime they're working with as being an "X+Y"-dimensional spacetime, where X is the number of spatial dimensions and Y is the number of time dimensions. Everyday reality is observed to be a 3+1-dimensional spacetime, an object confined to a flat plane can be modeled as inhabiting a 2+1-dimensional spacetime, a static object can be modeled as inhabiting a 3+0-dimensional spacetime, and so on. There are even spacetimes under study that have more than one time dimension, like 4+2-dimensional spacetimes; while they are completely and utterly unintuitive, general relativity is built in such a way that they can be analyzed without too much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost a 3D graphics question. The $(x, y, z)$ coordinates of your point can be taken relative to the cube, and the cube has it's own position relative to the "world". The motion of the cube can be taken as a *vector* $(x, y, z)$.

A vector describes a motion rather than a point. The vector is added to the position of the object at specific intervals. (So, a vector of $(1, 2, 3)$ would add $1$ to $x$, $2$ to $y$, and $3$ to $z$ every time interval). (In the real world this would be applied continuously; in a game, this is applied every "frame" instead.)

You can think of a vector as an "arrow" pointing in some (in this case 3D) direction and having some length representing a movement in that direction traveling that much distance in a given time interval. (The "arrow" has no specific *location* in space though, since it could be applied to any object.)

So, you have the cube located at some current position $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$, moving at some speed and direction $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ (which is added to the cube's position each time interval), and containing a point with coordinates relative to the cube $(x_3, y_3, z_3)$. The point could also be moving within the cube with another motion vector describing its relative motion.

And lastly, to get the absolute position of the point, you can treat its relative position in the cube as a vector, and treat the cube's position relative to the world as a vector from the origin, and add the two vectors together $(x_1 + x_3, y_1 + y_3, z_1 + z_3)$ to get a position vector relative to the origin describing the absolute position of the point in the cube. You would not "hang on" to this value as time progresses, since it would change over time. It would need to be recomputed for each instant in time.

Using calculus, which is beyond me, all of this can be described much more elaborately.

Answer (score 0):

Your question raises the principle of  moving reference frames. There is no absolute 'still' in the universe, so you can specify a framework of coordinates X,Y,Z, and I can specify a framework x,y,z, and the two frameworks can be moving relative to each other, so to be able to convert from one to the other you do indeed need to know their relative velocity.